# Division of 2 row values based on group and condition

Tags: r

I want to have to divide the values in the 4th column ("Count") of 2 rows, of which the first columns have the same value.

I tried to use 'group_by' but couldn't tell R that I want to divide the FAST Count value by the SLOW Count value. In other words, I couldn't figure out how to access those values individually.

```r
cells <- rep(c("CELL1","CELL2"), times =2 , each = 4)
temps <- rep(c(10,20,30,40), times = 4)
corners <- rep(c("FAST","SLOW"), times = 1, each = 8)
counts <- c(3200,5000,7250,10000,150,250,400,600,2400,12000,3600,2100,50,80,120,180)

df <- data.frame(cells,temps,corners,counts)
```

This code will generate a data-frame which looks like this:

```
    cells temps corners counts
    1  CELL1    10    FAST   3200
    2  CELL1    20    FAST   5000
    3  CELL1    30    FAST   7250
    4  CELL1    40    FAST  10000
    5  CELL2    10    FAST    150
    6  CELL2    20    FAST    250
    7  CELL2    30    FAST    400
    8  CELL2    40    FAST    600
    9  CELL1    10    SLOW   2400
    10 CELL1    20    SLOW  12000
    11 CELL1    30    SLOW   3600
    12 CELL1    40    SLOW   2100
    13 CELL2    10    SLOW     50
    14 CELL2    20    SLOW     80
    15 CELL2    30    SLOW    120
    16 CELL2    40    SLOW    180
```

Expected output is a new data-frame which contains cells, temps and division results:

```
       cells temps   div_result
    1  CELL1    10     1.33
    2  CELL1    20     0.42
    3  CELL1    30     2.01
    4  CELL1    40     4.55
    5  CELL2    10     3.00
    6  CELL2    20     3.13
    7  CELL2    30     3.33
    8  CELL2    40     3.33
```

Comment: `aggregate(counts ~ cells + temps, df, FUN = function(x) x[1] / x[2])` (you would need to reorder the result though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way with `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  group_by(cells, temps) %>% 
  summarize(
    div_result = counts[corners == "FAST"]/counts[corners == "SLOW"]
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  cells temps div_result
  <fct> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 CELL1    10      1.33 
2 CELL1    20      0.417
3 CELL1    30      2.01 
4 CELL1    40      4.76 
5 CELL2    10      3    
6 CELL2    20      3.12 
7 CELL2    30      3.33 
8 CELL2    40      3.33
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility involving `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(cells, temps) %>%
 summarise(div_result = first(counts)/last(counts))

  cells temps div_result
  <fct> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 CELL1    10      1.33 
2 CELL1    20      0.417
3 CELL1    30      2.01 
4 CELL1    40      4.76 
5 CELL2    10      3    
6 CELL2    20      3.12 
7 CELL2    30      3.33 
8 CELL2    40      3.33
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R`

```
by(df[['counts']], df[c('cells', 'temps')], FUN = function(x) x[1]/x[2])
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(div_results = first(counts)/last(counts)), .(cells, temps)]
```